# Save A Class Instance As JSON

Tags: r, json, r-s4

**Problem**

I am working on project with RC various custom made classes. I would like to save certain class instances at the end of my program in order to export them to a data base. I tried using `jsonlite::toJSON(account)` but I received the error message

> Error: No method for S4 class:BankAccount

**Class**

I have the following class

```
BankAccount <- setRefClass('BankAccount', 
                       fields  = list(
                         balance = 'numeric',
                         ledger = 'data.frame'
                         ),
                       methods = list(
                         deposit  = function (x) {
                           x <- max(x,0)
                           balance <<- balance + x
                           ledger <<- data.frame(
                             Date   = c(ledger$Date, as.character(Sys.time())),
                             Type   = c(ledger$Type, 'Deposit'),
                             Amount = c(ledger$Amount, x),
                             stringsAsFactors = FALSE
                           )
                          },
                         withdraw = function (x) {
                           x <- max(x,0)
                           balance <<- balance - x
                           ledger <<- data.frame(
                             Date   = c(ledger$Date, as.character(Sys.time())),
                             Type   = c(ledger$Type, 'Withdrawal'),
                             Amount = c(ledger$Amount, x),
                             stringsAsFactors = FALSE
                           )
                         }
                       ))
```

**Instance**

And here is an instance of that class

```
account <- BankAccount$new(balance = 100)
account$deposit(1000)
Sys.sleep(5)
account$withdraw(97.89)
account
Reference class object of class "BankAccount"
Field "balance":
[1] 1002.11
Field "ledger":
                 Date       Type  Amount
1 2018-12-31 16:21:20    Deposit 1000.00
2 2018-12-31 16:21:26 Withdrawal   97.89
```

**JSON**

Now I would like to save it to as a JSON file of the form (there might be a typo in the JSON - not that familiar with the format)

```
{
  "balance": "double",
  "ledger": {
    "Date": "string",
    "Type": "string",
    "Amount": "double"
  }
}
```

---

**PS**

I also tried without the field `ledger` (which is of class `data.frame`) but it still did not work.

---

**Edit**

Here is the output of `jsonlite::serializeJSON(account)`

```
{"type":"S4","attributes":{".xData":{"type":"environment","attributes":{},"value":{}}},"value":{"class":"BankAccount","package":".GlobalEnv"}}
```

As you can see it seems to only save information about the class `BankAccount` but not about the instance `account` (balance value etc. missing).

Comment: Did you try `jsonlite::serializeJSON`?

Comment: @IanWesley I did, it doesn't throw an error but it doesn't really behave as intended. See the edit.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @HongOoi MongoDB

Comment: jsonlite must know your object so that it can serialize it... if you have a custom class like in your case, you also must write your own toJSON method. Probably you will want to do something like extract the elements you care about into a list, and then use `toJSON()` on that list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a workaround (as indicated by @StefanF). One can add methods to classes

```
# converts to JSON
toJSON = function (prettifyy = TRUE) {
           instanceJSON <- jsonlite::toJSON(list(balance = balance,ledger  = ledger))
           if (prettifyy) instanceJSON <- jsonlite::prettify(instanceJSON)
           instanceJSON
         }
# saves as .json, e.g. path = 'C:/Test/instance.json'
saveJSON = function (path) {
             instanceJSON <- toJSON()
             writeLines(instanceJSON, path)
           }
```

The solution is not ideal as

- there is a bit of labor as one needs to specify which of the fields should be incorporated
- also, if a field of `BankAccount` is of class `MyClass` (another custom class), then you need to either specify which fields of `MyClass` are of relevance or create a `toJSON` as well for `MyClass`